# cannot load css styles from scss through view

Tags: css, angularjs, gulp

I cannot load styles to view  from scss ,below is gulp.js,

// Compile and Automatically Prefix Stylesheets

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {

     return gulp.src([
    'Content/styles/**/*.scss',
    'Content/styles/**/*.css'
  ])
    .pipe($.newer('Content/styles'))
    //.pipe($.newer('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass({
      precision: 10
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({ browsers: AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Content/styles'))
    //.pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    // Concatenate And Minify Styles
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssnano()))
    .pipe($.size({ title: 'styles' }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Content'));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using relative path

Comment: No havent tried by relative path, Can you please suggest edit

Comment: sorry ...are you sure to don't have to put also 'Content/styles/*.scss', and 'Content/styles/*.css' ??

Comment: i have subdirectory in between the styles and .css Content/styles/directory/*.scss

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Content is your directory, you can use relative path like:-

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {

     return gulp.src([
    './Content/styles/**/*.scss',
    './Content/styles/**/*.css'
  ])
    .pipe($.newer('./Content/styles'))
    //.pipe($.newer('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass({
      precision: 10
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({ browsers: AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Content/styles'))
    //.pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    // Concatenate And Minify Styles
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssnano()))
    .pipe($.size({ title: 'styles' }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Content'));
});
```